# Reduce PDF size generated by Quartz2D

Tags: ios, pdf-generation, quartz-2d

I want to generate PDF from UICollectionView using Quartz2D. The collectionView has many cells, per cell is a full screen view. I can generated the PDF, but the size is too large. I generated 8 pages of pdf, and the size is 2.8M. Generally,  I would have more than forty cells, and the pdf size would up to more than 20M. I want to send this pdf to other people using email, and it is far too large as an attach in email.

Meanwhile, When I open the pdf on my own MBP, it looks good. But when I open it at a PC, it looks poor.

Sorry about my English, I'm not a native speaker, if there are anything unclear in my description, please comment below, thanks.

Here is my code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0);

NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 198.0f, 153.0f), nil);
    for (NSInteger section = 0; section < [self.collectionView numberOfSections]; section++) {
        for (NSInteger item = 0; item < [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section]; item++) {

            UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self collectionView:self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section]];

            [self addPrintingViewPDF:cell.contentView];
        }
    }
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
});

- (void)addPrintingViewPDF:(UIView*)printingView {
    // Mark the beginning of a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Scale down from 1024x768 to fit paper output (792x612; 792/1024 = 0.773)
    CGContextScaleCTM(pdfContext, 0.193f, 0.199f);
    [printingView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
}
```

Comment: Does your PDF have images in it or just text?

Comment: It contains images and text.

Comment: I'm guessing that the images are what's causing the PDF's larger size but you can confirm by inspecting the PDF's properties. You'll need to manually compress the images, see [this snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15246178/231316) for the basic idea.