# Creating Multipage PDF File using CoreGraphics shows error on console

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I am having a problem in creating the multi page PDF.
I am using NSMutableData for storing the PDF data.
When I am drawing a new page using the following code

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
**    Error Line   **
```

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 595, 841), nil);

```
[self drawPageAtIndex:self.numberOfPages+1 inRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight)];
[self drawBorder];//draws Border to the page
```

It shows me following error on console

```
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with -2147483648.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with 2147483647.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with -2147483648.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with 2147483647.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with -2147483648.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with 2147483647.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with -2147483648.
<Error>: replacing +/-infinity with 2147483647.
```

Please can someone help me to resolve the error.

## [Here is the link which i reffered previously for the same error](https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/15799)

it says that core graphics logs are getting confusing values but i am not getting a resolution on the error
Thank You.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue have you found the solution?

Comment: No,The error are minimized i.e.previously it was showing me many number of lines with the above error but when i decreased the color shades for drawing the pdf the line lines are displaying less than 10,I think the issue is related with the color used for drawing the PDF.

Comment: I didnt use any color shades still in console shows the above errors. In this link question is my code Can you please have look once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461231/cant-create-pdf-and-print-more-than-60-pages-memory-raises-crashes

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the error and apparently fix it. I have an app on the App Store since 2013. The app creates some PDF files and the error showed for the first time in iOS 10.

I traced it to this snippet

```
    NSString* pgStr = [some text];        
    UIFont* theFont = [some font];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:theFont, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle
                                          };

    // ERROR        
    [pgStr drawInRect:[some frame] withAttributes:attributes];
```

To fix it, introduce line heights to the paragraph style:

```
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = theFont.pointSize;
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = theFont.pointSize;
```

Comment: i am still facing the errors even after adding above two lines. I getting the error exactly at same line i.e.when i am drawing the text to PDF

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug -

Open Radar Link: http://www.openradar.me/28250871